# Eigenvalue distribution for a real-valued random matrix with correlated Gaussian entries

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices

I'm working on an application where I would greatly benefit from knowing the distributions of the eigenvalues of a real-valued random matrix whose elements can be assumed to be Gaussian, but where I also know in advance that those matrix entries will likely be correlated. That is, the entries are distributed $MVN(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$. The matrix cannot be assumed to be symmetric. I'm totally new to random matrix theory and so I don't really know where to start and I'd really appreciate some suggestions and references on the following:

1. Is this a solved problem?
2. If not, are there adjacent problems that have been solved? Does it seem like a solution is a long way off and I should look for an alternative?
3. Is there a name for the kind of random matrix I'm describing (i.e., correlated Gaussian entries)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: for $\Sigma=1$ (uncorrelated Gaussians) this would be the Ginibre ensemble; for correlated elements the eigenvalue distribution is likely to become the same as in the Ginibre ensemble for large $N$, because of a central limit theorem; by the way: are you sure you need the eigenvalues and not the singular values (which would be the Wishart distribution)?

Comment: if all eigenvalues are zero, wouldnt the matrix itself be zero?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm actually not entirely sure what I need. I'm working on a hypothesis test for whether eigenvalues of a matrix would all be exactly 0. The advantage of such a test is to evaluate the chance that an observed graph (directed, fixed vertices, but random edges) has any cycles or is acyclic. Specifically, if all the eigenvalues of a directed graph's adjacency matrix are all 0, then the graph must be acyclic. Thus, it'd be helpful to test if an observed graph plausibly came from an acyclic population, by testing the eigenvalues of its adjacency matrix.

Comment: Oops, just finished editing. I might be wrong, but if I had a matrix whose only non-zero entries were in the upper triangle, wont all of the eigenvalues be 0? For example, in R, the eigenvalues are all 0

x <- matrix(
  c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 5, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  nrow = 5,
  byrow = T
)


eigen(x)

Comment: you're correct, my mistake;